# Calling through Spring a procedure with collection of object (oracle ARRAY STRUCT)

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate

im trying to execute a procedure which contains between others a parameter which is a collection of object (oracle). I have managed them lot of times without spring, but I'm a bit lost trying to do it with spring, althoug there is some information on the internet, I can't find a full example in order to compare my code. Spring doc has just fragments. Probably my code is wrong but i ignore why, could you help me? I'm running simplier procedures without problems. My DAO looks like this:

```
//[EDITED]
private SimpleJdbcCall pActualizaDia;

....

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
  pActualizaDia = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withCatalogName("PTR_GRUPOS_TRABAJO").withProcedureName("UPDATE_DIA");
  pActualizaDia.getJdbcTemplate().setNativeJdbcExtractor(new OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor());
}
...

 public Calendario updateSingle(final Calendario calendario) {

    SqlTypeValue cambiosEmpresa = new AbstractSqlTypeValue() {

    protected Object createTypeValue(Connection conn, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {

    ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = new ArrayDescriptor("TTPTR_CAMBIO_EMPRESA", conn);

    Object[] collection = new Object[calendario.getCambiosEmpresa().size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (CeAnoEmp ce : calendario.getCambiosEmpresa()) {
        collection[i++] = new STRUCT(new StructDescriptor("TPTR_CAMBIO_EMPRESA", conn), conn, new Object[] {
            ce.getSQLParam1(),
            //...more parameters here in order to fit your type.
            ce.getSQLparamn() });
    }

    ARRAY idArray = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, collection);

    return idArray;

    }

};

     MapSqlParameterSource mapIn = new MapSqlParameterSource();
 mapIn.addValue("P_ID_ESCALA", calendario.getEscala().getIdEscala());
     //more simple params here

     //Here it is the Oracle ARRAY working properly
 pActualizaDia.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("P_CAMBIOS_EMPRESA",
 OracleTypes.STRUCT, "TTPR_CAMBIO_EMPRESA"));
 mapIn.addValue("P_CAMBIOS_EMPRESA",cambiosEmpresa);

     //When executing the procedure it just work :)
     pActualizaDia.execute(mapIn);
     return null;
   }
```

The exception I get sais

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy91 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

I've been reading more about this topic and i found that It almost seems like if using Oracle Arrays you also have to cast the connection to be an oracle connection.

However, most Spring jdbc framework classes like SimpleJDBCTemplate and StoredProcedure hide the connection access from you. Do I need to subclass one of those and override a method somewhere to get the dbcp connection and then cast it to an Oracle connection?

Thank you very much.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy91 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection Sorry, i've included it into the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it finally, I've edited the post in order to have an example for anyone looking for a piece of code to solve this issue.

There are two important things to have in mind:

1) It's mandatory to set oracle extractor in jdbctemplate in order to cast properly the connection to get oracle functionality.

2) When using this extractor ojdbc and JRE version must be the same, any other case you'll get an abstractmethodinvocation exception.

Thanks anyone who tried to solve it and hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use spring to call a procedure with array of collection of oracle structure :  below a simple example to do this

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;



public class SpringObjectMapper {

    public static class SaveObjectFunction extends StoredProcedure {
        final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SavePackInterFunction.class);

        private static final String PROC_NAME = "schema.proc_name";
        private final static String ARRAY_OF_VALUE_PARAM_NAME = "ARRAY_OF_VALUE";
        private final static String OUT_PARAM_NAME = "out";

        public SaveObjectFunction(DataSource dataSource) {
            super(dataSource, PROC_NAME);
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter(ARRAY_OF_VALUE_PARAM_NAME, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "schema.array_object_type"));
            compile();
        }

        public String execute(Collection<Model> values) {
            logger.info("------------------------EnregInterlocuteurPrcedure::execute : begin----------------------------");
            String message = null;
            try {

                OracleConnection connection = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
                ArrayDescriptor arrayValueDescriptor = new ArrayDescriptor("schema.array_object_type", connection);
                StructDescriptor typeObjeDescriptor = new StructDescriptor("schema.object_type", connection);

                Object[] valueStructArray = new Object[values.size()];
                int i = 0;  
                for (Iterator<Model> iterator = values.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    Model model = (Model) iterator.next();
                    STRUCT s = new STRUCT(typeObjeDescriptor, connection, new Object[] {model.getAttribute1(), model.getAttribute2(), model.getAttribute3(),
                            model.getAttribute4(), model.getAttribute5(), model.getAttribute6(), model.getAttribute7()});
                    valueStructArray[i++] = s;
                }
                ARRAY inZoneStructArray = new ARRAY(arrayValueDescriptor, connection, valueStructArray);
                Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                inputs.put(ARRAY_OF_VALUE_PARAM_NAME, inZoneStructArray);
                Map<String, Object> out = super.execute(inputs);
                message = (String) out.get(OUT_PARAM_NAME);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return message;
        }
    }

}
```